# How to create shared object(.so) from .cc files

Tags: mysql, plugins, shared-objects

Can anyone please tell whether it is possible to create the `shared object`(.so) files from the existing **.cc** files?

Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple Google search.

Comment: Then pls suggest me the answer..

Comment: No one owes you anything here.  I'd suggest that you start relying less on SO and more on your own abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should look into make.

http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

You need to compile your object files and then create an shared object out of those.

Comment: is this also right?                                      `gcc -c -fPIC hello_world.cc -o hello_world.o`

`gcc hello_world.o -shared -o hello_world.so`

Comment: Did you try it?  You posted the comment 48 minutes ago.  You could have answered your own question ten times over if you'd simply tried it.

Comment: I the tried comment i have posted,but there is some error in compiling `.cc file`.So i could'nt get the `.so `file.Hence i asked whether is there any other method of generating `.so file` from `.cc files`.

Comment: Sounds like you have to fix the compilation error in the .cc file before you can proceed.  There's no magic here.    What's the .cc error?

Comment: ya i am trying to fix the .cc errrors,a part of the errors are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928140/asks-for-complete-directory-path-the-directory-is-present-yet-this-error-no-suc